# document.write angular-material fallback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Is there any static content in the minification for fallback. Looking for something like `window.angular.material`

```
<script>window.angular-material || document.write('<script src="../angular-material.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular-Material comes as a module so you can check that like this

```
<script>
  try { 
    angular.module("ngMaterial") 
  } catch(err) { 
    document.write('<script src="../angular-material.min.js"><\/script>')
  }
</script>
```